# How does SELECT FOR UPDATE actually work?

Tags: mysql, sql, concurrency, locking, queue

I'm trying to implement a queue using MYSQL, and want to make sure I'm understanding `SELECT FOR UPDATE` correctly.

My table:

```
Table jobs
Fields: id (INT), state (VARCHAR), queued_time (TIMESTAMP)
```

When I insert a job, the state is `QUEUED`. When I lock a job, the state becomes `PROCESSING`.

I have multiple machines, each using the same DB connection. When a machine is ready to grab something off the queue, it calls

```
SELECT FROM jobs WHERE state = "QUEUED" ORDER BY queued_time ASC LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE; UPDATE jobs SET state = "PROCESSING" WHERE state = "QUEUED" ORDER BY queued_time ASC LIMIT 1;
```

After the query, I check if the `UPDATE` succeeded, and if it did, I allow the machine to process the job returned by the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`.

Let's say machines 1 and 2 are ready to grab something off the queue. The queue looks like this:

```
id        state        queued_time
1         QUEUED       2014-03-30 20:04:43
2         QUEUED       2014-03-30 22:04:43
```

Machine 1 will execute the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` at time `t1`, and the `UPDATE` at time `t2`. What happens when machine 2 executes both `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and the `UPDATE` between `t1` and `t2`? Which of these happen?

```
- Machine 1 ends up with job 1, and machine 2's `UPDATE` fails because machine 1 locked the row and never unlocked it (this is my current understanding)

- Machine 2 ends up with job 1, and machine 1's `UPDATE` fails

- Both machines end up with job 1
```

What happens when machine 2 executes `SELECT FOR UPDATE` between `t1` and `t2`, and `UPDATE` after `t2`? Which of these happen?

```
- Machine 1 ends up with job 1, and machine 2's `UPDATE` fails

- Machine 2 ends up with job 1, and machine 1's `UPDATE` fails

- Both machines end up with job 1 because machine 2's `UPDATE` succeeds since machine 1 release the lock (this is my current understanding)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to execute these actions inside of a transaction (`autocommit=0`) because `SELECT FOR UPDATE` only holds the lock until the transaction completes.

None of your scenarios occur. The transactions won't immediately fail, but they may time out.

If transaction 2 attempts to lock the same record as transaction 1 (the lock occurs in the `SELECT FOR UPDATE`), transaction 2 will have to wait until transaction 1 completes. If the lock time out period (innodb_lock_wait_timeout) is reached, then the transaction will time out ("fail").

Ensure that any time you want to select the record and obey any current locks that you use `SELECT FOR UPDATE`. A normal `SELECT` without `FOR UPDATE` won't wait for any locks.

You should, obviously, attempt to finish any transaction as quickly as possible.

Your method should work fine. You should consider retrieving the primary key value in the `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement and then simply reference the record by the primary key value in the `UPDATE` statement.